# Can't compile project with openssl on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl, g++

I'm can't compile my project with openssl on Ubuntu. Yes, I'm install libssl-dev. My command for compile is: `g++ --std=c++11 [files] -lssl` .
Write error like a:

> "undefined reference to `RSA_generate_key`"

I'm using Google a lot of time for search solve for this problem. 
Please help compile my project. Maybe need install any others packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to RSA\_generate\_key in OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649685/undefined-reference-to-rsa-generate-key-in-openssl)